# Using String IDs with TinkerGraph

Tags: c#, .net, gremlin-server, tinkergraph

I'm pointing some .Net code at Tinkergraph, for testing purposes, that uses Neptune when deployed. Our Neptune database uses Strings as IDs (always UUIDs, but string objects)

When I query the graph features from the console (I'm using the standard docker image with some tweaks) I see:-

```
NumericIds: true,
StringIds: true,
UuidIds: true
```

I have been unable to find a way to get the graph to use strings as IDs. The best I've managed is to switch it to UUIDs.

```
gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexIdManager=UUID

gremlin.tinkergraph.edgeIdManager=UUID

gremlin.tinkergraph.vertexPropertyIdManager=UUID
```

This can work, but has meant I've had to change a lot of casts in the original C# code to .ToString() and do a bit of extra work around code that uses dymanics.

Ideally, I'd like the returned Ids to be strings, not System.Guid.

I have looked through the Java code at the IdManagers and I can't see a STRING one.  Is there one in the default implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than specify UUID or LONG use ANY to enable String IDs with TinkerGraph.

The possible values are defined in this file: https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/structure/TinkerGraph.DefaultIdManager.html

Comment: Thanks.  That cleared something up. Am I right in thinking that Tinkergraph will hand-out LONGs when the Ids aren't user-supplied in this case?

Comment: Yes when ANY is set if you do not specify an explicit ID (of an explicit type) TinkerGraph generates LONG IDs.